# Is it possible to dig through a damp stone?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I keep running into damp stones every where.  Is there a way to get through them, or do I have to make a separate cave for them?  Also, can I use them to make mud? I still haven't quite figured out farming.  Or hunting for that matter...

Comment: To address your side-note, there is an excellent explanation of basic underground farming at http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/2604/how-do-i-make-a-farm-using-buckets

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can dig through damp stone, if you know what you're doing (don't accidentally break into a river without proper precautions! but going under a pond is ok). What you have to do is designate the square again.

[Aquifers](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/v0.34:Aquifer) are another matter entirely. Take a look at the wiki on how to deal with them - I have been scared of them and avoid them on embark.

You can't make mud from damp stone, for that you need to let water flow over ground. Also see the wiki.

Post your other questions as separate ones, and I'll see what I can do :-)

Comment: Great.  I followed your instructions and now my entire cave has flooded.  Great work. :-p

Comment: Well, that's what I meant with 'if you know what you're doing'! You can build walls if you're lucky and otherwise: Have fun!

Comment: hey is there any way to tell the dwarves to just ignore damp stone and go for it? building a tunnel a full floor underneath a river takes forever...

Comment: I did get the wall up in time and none of my dwarves drowned. Is there any way to reclaim the area?

Comment: pump the water out with a screw pump. http://df.magmawiki.com/index.php/DF2010:Screw_pump

Comment: @Epaga: I think that may just be possible in the new version (.31) - see http://df.magmawiki.com/index.php/DF2010:Announcement. Not 100% sure if that works for damp/hot stone, though!

Comment: @RitwikBose, first time I've read that comment as "I've accidentally get the wall up in time and none of my dwarves drowned! Is there any way to reset the area and try again?"